# display base currency symbol in checkout

Tags: currency

My store base currency is AUD and the local store displays the currency values with A$, I have an international store which has currency displayed in USD. The catalog items all display on US$. When I go to checkout-payment page in International store the symbol next to this text "Your credit card will be charged for" displays as just $ instead of A$. The amount however gets converted correctly to AUD. How to display the symbol as A$. I have attached screenshot of the same.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

For Magento 1:

Goto system -> Manage Currencies -> Symbols

And then change the currency symbol for AUD which is currently you have set $ to A$.

Comment: I am looking for magento2

Comment: Yes the same feature is also available on magento 2.